# Get the selected tag name from a html form using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to ask if there is a way to get the current selected tag name from a form .To make it more clear please take a look at the example below .

```
<form name='get_state'  id="catalog" action='post.php' method='POST' >
 <select name='plateDescr' onchange="window.loadStates()"></select>
 <select id="matType"  name="matType" onchange="window.loadStates()" hidden="hidden"></select>
</form>
```

For example if the select tag with name 'plateDescr' is currently selected i want to get exactly this value 'plateDescr'. Is there anyway of doing this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean the field in focus? a value is selected and the field is focused

Comment: `document.activeElement.name` should return `plateDescr`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you very much for the fast response.